# Update servers with shinken, check_apt and event_handler

Tags: hibernate, event-handling, upgrade

I want to be alerted of critical updates by Shinken. I use check_apt but it returns me 0 updates but when there are updates. Then I want to launch a event_handler when the alert goes critical. These are the files:
commands.cfg

```
# 'check_apt' command definition
define command {
    command_name    check_apt
    command_line    /usr/local/shinken/libexec/check_apt
    }
 define command {
  command_name    upgrade_server
  command_line    sudo /usr/local/shinken/libexec/upgrade $SERVICESTATE$ $SERVICESTATETYPE$ $SERVICEATTEMPT$
```

script upgrade :

```
  #!/bin/sh
   #
  # Event handler script for upgrade server
  #
  #
 case "$1" in
OK)

 ;;
  WARNING)

  ;;
  UNKNOWN)

   ;;
   CRITICAL)
  case "$2" in

  case "$3" in

    # Wait until the check has been tried 3 times before restarting the web server.
    # If the check fails on the 4th time (after we restart the web server), the state
    # type will turn to "hard" and contacts will be notified of the problem.
    # Hopefully this will restart the web server successfully, so the 4th check will
    # result in a "soft" recovery. If that happens no one gets notified because we
    # fixed the problem!
    3)
      echo -n "Mise à jour ...."
    #lancement de la commande 
     /usr/bin/aptitude -y full-upgrade
      ;;
    esac
    ;;


  HARD)
      echo -n "Mise à jour ...."
    #lancement de la commande 
     /usr/bin/aptitude -y full-upgrade
    ;;
  esac
  ;;
      esac
      exit 0
```

and services.cfg :

```
  ## In this directory you can put all your specific service
   # definitions
   define service{
    use                             generic-service
    host_name                       router
     service_description             APT
     check_command                   check_apt!
     }

   define service{
   host_name    router
   service_description   APT
     max_check_attempts    4
     event_handler    upgrade_server
      }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i think you are wrong in the definition service way.
You need to define the APT service:
`define service{
    use                             generic-service
    host_name                       router
    service_description             APT
    check_command                   check_apt!
    max_check_attempts              4
    event_handler                   upgrade_server
    }`
and you should not separate them.
I tried and it worked fine.